# Синхронизация запроса

Tags: java, android

Есть приложение, в котором идет запрос на сервер. Как сделать чтобы прогресс бар ждал ответ от сервера и выводил что надо. Думал как-то синхронизировать запрос, чтобы все шло по очереди, но не знаю как это сделать.

Comment: Конкретизируйте вопрос: как запрос посылаете? Как обрабатываете ответ? Откуда посылаете? и т.п.